# set new content-type as product in ubercart

Tags: 6, ubercart

When I install Ubercart, it creates a new content type ("Product"), and uses it for handling products.

Can I create another content type, and use it as product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. It is a bit confusing the first time you try, as Ubercart terminology is different for some reason; they call it *product class*, but it is just a new content type.